# Yii model isNewRecord false due to constructor

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

In Yii ActiveRecord, is it possible to set an attribute in a model constructor and still have the model's isNewRecord property remain true?

I have a model constructor to create a private attribute to hold a PHPPass Password hash instance. When I do this, it sets the isNewRecord property to false, even though the record is created new.

I tried a workaround with call to setIsNewRecord(true) in the constructor if the id attribute is greater than zero, but it appears attributes are not available in the constructor.

I had to remove the constructor, and make the statement in each method requiring phpass.

Constructor for User model:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->phpass=new PasswordHash(Yii::app()->params['phpass']['iteration_count_log2'], Yii::app()->params['phpass']['portable_hashes']);
}
```

User model init and isNewRecord condition in controller

```
public function actionEdit($id = null)
{

    $myModel = new User();       
    echo $myModel->isNewRecord;   //false due to constructor
}
```

Comment: can you show the workaround you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When ovveriding contstructor **make sure to call parent constructor**. Always call parent constructor when ovveriding, unless you know what you are doing.

```
public function __construct($scenario = 'insert'){
    parent::__construct($scenario);
    $this->phpass=new PasswordHash(Yii::app()->params['phpass']['iteration_count_log2'], Yii::app()->params['phpass']['portable_hashes']);
}
```

Also phpass can be stored as static property, you don't need a new instance of phpass for each active record instance.

**EDIT:** Thanks @Kevin for link to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119141/when-overriding-a-method-should-my-custom-code-come-before-or-after-superbase) about ovverding constructors.

One more **important** note to add: Remember to pass parameters to constructor. In Yii model classes there is `$scenario` param with default value `insert`. When you ovveride constructor without passing this argument, there will be always `insert` scenario, and there will not be any error message about missing param, because it has default value. I Updated code with `$scenario`.

Comment: As an extension to this answer, you might want to look at the accepted answer to the following question. It defines your options for calling parent::__contstruct() and when you should call it before your code, after, or not at all in a very clear way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119141/when-overriding-a-method-should-my-custom-code-come-before-or-after-superbase

Answer (score 3):

In general you should avoid to override the constructor in Yii classes. Most components provide a [`init()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#init-detail) method instead which is the right place for code like in your example.

The difference is, that for *application components* the object will already have all configuration applied. That's not relevant in your case but still it's good practice to use `init()` instead of `__construct()`.